# How to make bottom navigation bar blur with background in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

## I don't know how to make the bottom navigation bar blur with the background in Flutter as shown below[image]

I want the bottom navigation bar to blur the background near the bottom of the screen, but I can only do it below with a white background with two very thick top and bottom borders that obscure the content

[image]

here is my code,

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  var currentIndex = 0;
  //int currentIndex = 0;
  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
      HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
    });
  }

  final screens = [
    const HomePage(),
    NotificationPage(),
    MessagePage(),
    BookmarkPage(),
  ];

  List<IconData> listOfIcons = [
    Icons.home_rounded,
    Icons.notifications,
    Icons.message_rounded,
    Icons.library_books,
  ];

  List<String> listOfStrings = [
    'Home',
    'T.báo',
    'T.Nhắn',
    'B.Đăng',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double displayWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(child: screens[currentIndex]),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(displayWidth * .03),
        height: displayWidth * .155,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.1),
              blurRadius: 30,
              offset: Offset(0, 10),
            ),
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        ),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 4,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: displayWidth * .02),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                currentIndex = index;
                HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
              });
            },
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                  width: index == currentIndex
                      ? displayWidth * .32
                      : displayWidth * .18,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                    curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                    height: index == currentIndex ? displayWidth * .12 : 0,
                    width: index == currentIndex ? displayWidth * .32 : 0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: index == currentIndex
                          ? Color(0xffEC1C24).withOpacity(.2)
                          : Colors.transparent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                  width: index == currentIndex
                      ? displayWidth * .31
                      : displayWidth * .18,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          AnimatedContainer(
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                            curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                            width:
                                index == currentIndex ? displayWidth * .13 : 0,
                          ),
                          AnimatedOpacity(
                            opacity: index == currentIndex ? 1 : 0,
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                            curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                            child: Text(
                              index == currentIndex
                                  ? '${listOfStrings[index]}'
                                  : '',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xffEC1C24),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                fontSize: 15,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          AnimatedContainer(
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                            curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                            width:
                                index == currentIndex ? displayWidth * .03 : 20,
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            listOfIcons[index],
                            size: displayWidth * .076,
                            color: index == currentIndex
                                ? Color(0xffEC1C24)
                                : Colors.black26,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Thank you very much for your comments and contributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's relatively simple, first you need to set the body to `extendBody: true` in the Scaffold, this will make the bottomNavigation over the body of the scaffold.

It is important that the content of the body is as `Clip.none`, as I did with the `SingleChildScrollView`, this is to prevent the content from being cut before BottomNavigation.

For bottomNavigation, we will use a stack to add its bar over the [backdropfilter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html), which will blur the content.

full code

```
class MyBottomNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyBottomNavigation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyBottomNavigation> createState() => _MyBottomNavigationState();
}

class _MyBottomNavigationState extends State<MyBottomNavigation> {
  var currentIndex = 0;
  //int currentIndex = 0;
  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  final pageColumn = [
    Text('''What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

Where can I get some?
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.''', textAlign: TextAlign.justify,),
  ];

  final screens = [
    Container(),
    Container(),
    Container(),
    Container(),
  ];

  List<IconData> listOfIcons = [
    Icons.home_rounded,
    Icons.notifications,
    Icons.message_rounded,
    Icons.library_books,
  ];

  List<String> listOfStrings = [
    'Home',
    'T.báo',
    'T.Nhắn',
    'B.Đăng',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double displayWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(child:SingleChildScrollView(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        child: Column(children: pageColumn),
      )),
      extendBody: true,
      bottomNavigationBar: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          ClipRect(
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                sigmaX: 1.0,
                sigmaY: 1.0,
              ),
              child: Container(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  height: displayWidth * .180,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0)
              )
            )
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(displayWidth * .03),
            height: displayWidth * .155,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.1),
                  blurRadius: 30,
                  offset: Offset(0, 10),
                ),
              ],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            ),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 4,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: displayWidth * .02),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentIndex = index;
                  });
                },
                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                      curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                      width: index == currentIndex
                          ? displayWidth * .32
                          : displayWidth * .18,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                        curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                        height: index == currentIndex ? displayWidth * .12 : 0,
                        width: index == currentIndex ? displayWidth * .32 : 0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: index == currentIndex
                              ? Color(0xffEC1C24).withOpacity(.2)
                              : Colors.transparent,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                      curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                      width: index == currentIndex
                          ? displayWidth * .31
                          : displayWidth * .18,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              AnimatedContainer(
                                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                                curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                                width:
                                index == currentIndex ? displayWidth * .13 : 0,
                              ),
                              AnimatedOpacity(
                                opacity: index == currentIndex ? 1 : 0,
                                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                                curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                                child: Text(
                                  index == currentIndex
                                      ? '${listOfStrings[index]}'
                                      : '',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xffEC1C24),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              AnimatedContainer(
                                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                                curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                                width:
                                index == currentIndex ? displayWidth * .03 : 20,
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                listOfIcons[index],
                                size: displayWidth * .076,
                                color: index == currentIndex
                                    ? Color(0xffEC1C24)
                                    : Colors.black26,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but how do I replace the pageColumn with my original page screens? I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Replace my body with your `body: SafeArea(child: screens[currentIndex])`. Just see how the clip will look on your pages, if your screens are using ListView or SingleChildScrollView, you will need to mark the clipBehavior properties as Clip.none .

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm, but my screen is not using ListView or SingleChildScrollView, but using Column, Row, Expanded,... how can I still use it without having to convert to ListView or SingleChildScrollView

Comment: I fixed it thanks to your way, you are awesome, thank you very much

Comment: The clip is necessary because of the safeArea, one way to solve this is to remove the safeArea and inside the screen add a space at the end of the scroll for the scroll to exit the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

`bottomNavigationBar` is render below body in scaffold so they cannot collapse.

You could use `stack` instead to stack your custom navigation bar onto the body content and use `BackdropFilter` to blur out the background

here's the sample code:

```
body: Stack(
      children: [
        ListView(
          children: [
          ],
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            Spacer(),
            ClipRect(
              // set boundary for BackdropFilter
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                  sigmaX: 2,
                  sigmaY: 2,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      // this is your bottomNavBar
                      height: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.1),
                            blurRadius: 30,
                            offset: Offset(0, 10),
                          ),
                        ],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 16.0,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
```